# Show that for each integer $n ≥ 2$, $F_n$ is a finite index subgroup of $F_2$, where $F_n$ is the free group on $n$ generators.

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, free-groups

I'm trying to answer a problem which asks me to show **(using covering spaces)** that for each integer $n ≥ 2$, $F_n$ is a finite index
subgroup of $F_2$, where $F_n$ is the free group on $n$ generators.

I can see that if I can find some covering space with fundamental group $F_n$ of the wedge $S^1 \vee S^1$ then this will give me the existence of the subgroup, and I know that this will be of finite index if this covering map sends finitely many points to the vertex joining the two circles in $S^1 \vee S^1$.

The problem I'm having is I'm struggling to find such a covering space - the only space I know of with fundamental group $F_n$ is the wedge of $n$ circles, but I can't see any covering map from that to $S^1 \vee S^1$ so I assume I must need another.

If anyone could suggest such a covering space (and if so how I can show it has fundamental group $F_n$) I'd really appreciate the help!

Comment: Check [this out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045633/show-that-the-free-group-on-n-generators-is-a-finite-index-subgroup-of-f-2?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in reading the first few pages of [Hatcher's](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/ATch1.pdf) section on covering spaces (starts page 56, 65 in pdf). I'll be taking the pictures from there.

let the wedge $S^1 \vee S^1$ be labeled as follows:

[image]

And consider the space of $n$ circles connected together $\bigcirc\!\!\bigcirc\cdots \bigcirc\!\!\bigcirc$ as in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045633/show-that-the-free-group-on-n-generators-is-a-finite-index-subgroup-of-f-2?rq=1) linked in the comments. This will be our covering space.

We're going to label this space as follows:

[image]

(This is a particular case, but you get the idea)

Hopefully it's clear that if I send each labeled edges (preserving orientation) to their corresponding edges in $S^1 \vee S^1$, we get a covering map. It remains to show that this space has fundamental group of $F_n$.

To do this, imagine taking the bottom left $b$ edge and gradually contracting it until it disappears (the two endpoint are now one). The upper left $b$ is now a circle, so we have two circles (left $a$, upper left $b$) wedged with a figure eight. This process doesn't change the fundamental group (fill in the details).

Do the same thing with the bottom right $a$. We now have a $4$-rose! Because the process doesn't change the fundamental group, this means the space we started with has fundamental group $F_4$.

It seems like you know how to complete the rest of the proof about finite index subgroups.